# Unable to restart Unicorn in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, unicorn, systemd

I am trying to deploy my new rails app to Ubuntu 16.04 Digital Ocean Server. Here Unicorn is managed via `systemd`. This is my **/etc/systemd/system/unicorn.service** file

```
[Unit]
Description=Skreem Application
Before=nginx.service
Requires=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=rails
Group=rails

RuntimeDirectory=DigitalOceanOneClick
SyslogIdentifier=DigitalOceanRailsOneClick

# Go paranoid
PrivateTmp=true
PrivateDevices=true
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectKernelTunables=true
NoNewPrivileges=true

WorkingDirectory=/home/rails/skreem-ror
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/rails/skreem-ror/.unicorn.sh              

TimeoutSec=60s
RestartSec=10s
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I am trying to restart the unicorn service, I am getting following error

```
Failed to restart unicorn.service: Unit unicorn.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status unicorn.service' for details.
```

Then I tried `systemctl status unicorn.service` and getting

```
Jul 03 10:05:06 skreem-dev2 systemd[1]: unicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 03 10:05:06 skreem-dev2 systemd[1]: unicorn.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 03 10:05:06 skreem-dev2 systemd[1]: unicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 03 10:05:07 skreem-dev2 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/unicorn.service:18] Unknown lvalue 'ProtectKernelTunables' in section 'Service'
Jul 03 10:05:07 skreem-dev2 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/unicorn.service:32] Missing '='.
Jul 03 10:05:16 skreem-dev2 systemd[1]: unicorn.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 03 10:05:16 skreem-dev2 systemd[1]: unicorn.service: Failed to schedule restart job: Unit unicorn.service is not loaded properly: Invalid a
Jul 03 10:05:16 skreem-dev2 systemd[1]: unicorn.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 03 10:05:16 skreem-dev2 systemd[1]: unicorn.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Jul 03 11:33:51 skreem-dev2 systemd[1]: Stopped DigitalOcean Rails One-Click Application.
```

Its not coming from my updated `unicorn.service` file. Is it because my changes are not loading properly. Please help me to solve this issue.